# Whitelist validation for http request

Tags: java, xss, servlet-filters, whitelist, owasp

I am trying to create a servlet request filter which filters any incoming request based on the whitelist characters.

I want to accept only those characters which matches the whitelist pattern to avoid any malicious code to be executed by the attacker in the form of script or modified URL.

Does anyone know which whitelist characters should be used for filtering any HTTP request string?

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Implement pattern matching mechanism to find whitelist characters from your URL pattern by using RegEx..

Follow this **[link1](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2073192/core-java/regular-expressions-simplify-pattern-matching-code.html)**

**Or you can try:**

```
if (inputUrl.contains(whiteList)) {
  // your code goes here
}
```

**Or If you need to know where it occurs, you can use indexOf:**

```
int index = inputUrl.indexOf(whiteList);
if (index != -1) // -1 means "not found"
{
    ...
}
```

Thanks,

**~Chandan**

Comment: Thanks Chandan for the reply...Regex can b used to generate regular expressions ,since I am a newbie I have no idea which characters should be used for whitelist validation....

Comment: ~welcome androidDev, can you give an idea about your whitelist (what pattern, rules you want for it)

Comment: I am using struts framework where I want to validate each incoming request coming in the URL so I am searching for a regular expression which I can use for whitelist validation of url.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that "malicious" is very broad term. You should have clear idea what types of attacks are you trying to protect from and then take measures to prevent it.

You cannot specify set of characters in general which need to be filtered out, you need to know domain in which your input in url will be used. Generally dangerous is not url itself but url parameters which are provided by your users and then interpreted by your application. Depending on how your application will use this input, you need to take specific precautions. So for example:

1. Url param is used to determine target of redirect. User can use this to navigate victim to malicious site, site which masks as your site but will steal users credentials providing false credentials and so on. In that case you should construct whitelist of allowed destinations expected by your aplication and forbid others. See OWASP top TEN - [Unvalidated redirects and forwards](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Unvalidated_Redirects_and_Forwards_Cheat_Sheet).
2. You save data from url param to DB. You should prevent SQL injection by using Parametrized queries. [See OWASP SQL injection Cherat Sheet,](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet)
3. Url param data will be displayed as html. You should sanitize your html by some already proven sanitizer such as [OWASP html sanitizer](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Java_HTML_Sanitizer_Project) or [AntiSamy](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_AntiSamy_Project) to prevent [Cross Site Scripting](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_%28XSS%29).

And so on...

The point is, there is no silver bullet to protect you from all the malicious attack vectors especially not by whitelisting certain characters in servlet filter. You should know where is potentially malicious data used and process it with its specific usage in mind because different targets will have different vulnerabilities and will require different measures for protection.

Good start for high level overview of security issues and measures form protection against them is [OWASP TOP TEN](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2013-Top_10). Then I recommend some more detailed guides and resources provided by owasp.